# Initiating 2nd I2C bus on ESP32 with CCS811 sensor

Tags: i2c, esp32

I want to connect two CCS811 sensors with ESP32 dev board. Since the sensors have fixed address, I am unable to use them simultaneously. I have read that on ESP32 multiple I2C buses can be created. While trying to follow that route I tried to modify the library but I am stuck. I can't simply pass different pins for SDA and SCL when calling ccs.begin() function. It only takes one argument and that is the sensor address (code chunk from library below):

```
bool Adafruit_CCS811::begin(uint8_t addr) {
  _i2caddr = addr;

  _i2c_init();

  SWReset();
  delay(100);

  // check that the HW id is correct
  if (this->read8(CCS811_HW_ID) != CCS811_HW_ID_CODE)
    return false;

  // try to start the app
  this->write(CCS811_BOOTLOADER_APP_START, NULL, 0);
  delay(100);
```

and the actual wire.begin() function is called in the _i2c_init() function which is defined in the lib as:

```
void Adafruit_CCS811::_i2c_init() {
  Wire.begin();
#ifdef ESP8266
  Wire.setClockStretchLimit(500);
#endif
}
```

With my very basic knowledge of classes and object, I am unable to modify the library to make it work with 2 I2C buses. Could you please help me with this?

Link to Adafruit CCS811 library:(https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CCS811/blob/master/Adafruit_CCS811.cpp)

My Code so far:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_CCS811.h"

Adafruit_CCS811 ccs1;
Adafruit_CCS811 ccs2;


TwoWire sen1 = TwoWire(0);
TwoWire sen2 = TwoWire(1);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println(F("CCS811 test"));

  if (!ccs1.begin(25, 26, 100000))
  {
    Serial.println("CCS 1 Failed.");
    //while (1);
  } else {
    Serial.println("CCS 1 OK!");
  }

  // Wait for the sensor to be ready
  //while (!ccs.available());
}

void loop()
{
  if (ccs1.available())
  {
    if (!ccs1.readData())
    {
      Serial.println(" This is CSS");
      Serial.print("CO2: ");
      Serial.print(ccs1.geteCO2());
      Serial.print("ppm, TVOC: ");
      Serial.println(ccs1.getTVOC());
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("ERROR!");
      //while (1);
    }
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: CSS811 chip can have either address 0x5A or 0x5B depend on the logic level of ADDR pin. Read the [datasheet](https://www.sciosense.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/CCS811-Datasheet.pdf).

Comment: Yes the chip can but the module I am using can't. There is no ADDR pin.

Comment: which module do you use then? the module will include either a pull up or a pull down resistor. Instead of using an extra I2C bus for the second sensor you could buy one which has the address pin broken out (for a clean solution) or desolder the onboard pullup/-down and control it with a gpio or hardwire it to Vcc/Gnd with a solder bridge.

Comment: I use this module https://www.banggood.com/CJMCU-811V1-CCS811-NTC-CO2-eCO2-TVOC-Air-Mass-Sensor-p-1250571.html?cur_warehouse=CN&rmmds=search. I know I could buy another sensor but I also want to learn to use the second I2C bus on ESP32. That's why I trying to implement it this way